# "if not" vs "unless"

Tags: conditional-constructions, negation

I can't clearly understand why

1) My wife will be angry unless I get home by 7 o’clock. - is not correct while

2) My wife will be angry if I am not home by 7 o’clock. - is correct.

Any guiding line?

Comment: I would like to know who suggested (1) is wrong?

Comment: @JuliandotNot It's from *Practical English Usage* by Michael Swan, which is a great grammar book for learners (except for this entry, perhaps), imho. Unfortunately, this is not the best example in his book, and I guess that it sounded wrong to him when he wrote it (obviously, he suggested that the meaning of "My wife will be angry unless I get home by 7 o’clock." is "My wife's anger will be the result of me not getting home by 7 o'clock.") -- To understand why he wrote that entry (as a warning for learners, I believe), try this example of mine, "You will die unless you don't get hit by a car."

Comment: I'd probably say "unless I *am* home" rather than "unless I *get* home", but other than that it seems fine to me. @DamkerngT.'s final example sounds wrong because it requires the listener to make quite some effort to disentangle the real meaning of the sentence from the double negative.

Comment: @tobyink Thank you for the observation. The book uses "if I'm not home" indeed, whereas the marked as incorrect version is "unless I get home". I know that the wife example doesn't make the difference as clear as one would hope. However, even in that example, I'd say (for the sake of learners) that there is a fine difference between a wife who "will be angry unless I get home by 7 o'clock" and a wife who "will be angry if I'm not home by 7 o'clock". Then again, people might perceive things differently these days (from ten years ago, when the latest edition of the book, afaik, came out).

Answer (score 12):

Both are correct - *if...not* is what *unless* means. But the *unless* version suggests that her anger is expected, and only my arriving at or before 7 o'clock will prevent it, while the *if...not* version suggests that my arriving after 7 o'clock will trigger her anger.

Comment: I think the point you make is subtle, but true. For all that, I can't see why Michael Swan would single out #1 as "not correct". Would it make any difference if we slightly changed the "default, but potentially avoidable" consequence to something slightly more "predictable", such as *"My wife will drink too many preprandial martinis and get stinking drunk and angry unless I get home by 7 o’clock"* ???

Comment: @FumbleFingers That's a delightful context ... I'm not particularly surprised that even MS should nod. I very often see people here and on ELU , get specific contexts fixed in their minds and write as if that were the only relevant context. (And I'm as guilty as anybody - I did that just this morning.)

Comment: It's not just Michael Swan, although the above example is removed from the latest edition of _Practical English Usage_. "I’ll be angry unless the bus is on time." [Scott Thornbury](https://www.onestopenglish.com/ask-the-experts/grammar-unless-and-if/146350.article) "I'll be very surprised unless I get the job." John Eastwood, _Oxford Learner's Grammar_ "I'll be amazed unless Christie wins." Martin Hewings, _Advanced Grammar in Use_

Comment: It's my understanding as _a non-native_ English teacher: Using _unless_ in the above examples doesn't show that a feeling would _result_ from something not happening. In conditional sentences, a condition triggers a result, but the above examples don't show this cause-and-effect relationship and that's why learners are asked to avoid them. Please correct me if I'm wrong.